# Read Astro Config Values

Tags: astrojs

My astro.config.mjs is as follows:

```
export default defineConfig({
  compressHTML: false,
  experimental: {
    contentCollectionCache: true,
  },
  build: {
    assets: "_custom"
  },
  integrations: [
  ]
})
```

During an SSG build is it possible to get a reference to build.assets from astro.config.mjs

Comment: you mean you want to get the string `"_custom"`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is using an integration that exposes the Astro config using a virtual module, here is an example using [`astro-integration-kit`](https://astro-integration-kit.netlify.app/utilities/add-virtual-import/)

```js
import type { AstroIntegration } from "astro";
import { addVirtualImport } from "astro-integration-kit";

export default function myIntegration(): AstroIntegration {
    return {
        name: "my-integration",
        hooks: {
            "astro:config:setup": ({ config, updateConfig }) => {
                addVirtualImport({
                    name: 'virtual:my-integration/config',
                    content: `export default ${JSON.stringify(config)}`,
                    updateConfig,
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'astro/config'
import myintegration from './myintegration';

export default defineConfig({
  integrations: [myintegration()]
})
```

```js
import config from 'virtual:my-integration/config';

console.log(config.build.assets)
```